# Biometric Auth Stops VOIP In Background

Tags: ios, swift, voip

I have been using VoIP calls in the app. when biometric auth is disabled app call works fine but when biometric auth is enabled VoIP calls work in the foreground when authentication is successful but it does not work when the app is in the background or killed

Comment: Please be more specific. What does `but it does not work when the app is in the background or killed` mean. No calls arive? Calls get interrupted?

Comment: App works fine in the background, killed or active mode with VoIP and call kit, when biometric is disabled for app
It created an issue when I enable biometrics and app is in background or killed mode
Even other functionalities like share extension also do not works in this case for my app 
@burnsi